# Froala - image upload JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am using [Froala editor](http://editor.froala.com/) for my website. This editor have built in image upload function - image upload is working fine, but I am having trouble with response.

This is from the documentation:

```
The server processes the HTTP request.
The server has to process the upload request, save the image and return a hashmap containing a link to the uploaded image. The returned hashmap needs to look like: { link: 'path_to_uploaded_file/file.png' }
```

This is my function for returning link:

```
public function froala_upload()
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $folder = 'public/img/media';
        $slika = $this->site->single_upload($folder, 'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|JPG|JPEG|PNG|BMP');
        $link = array("link" => $slika);

        echo json_encode($link);
    }
```

This is JS code:

```
$('textarea').editable({
  inlineMode: false,
  imageUploadParam: "userfile",
  imageUploadURL: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/froala_upload",
  // Set the image error callback.
  imageErrorCallback: function (data) {
      // Bad link.
      if (data.errorCode == 1) {
        console.log(data);
      }

      // No link in upload response.
      else if (data.errorCode == 2) {
        console.log(data);
      }

      // Error during file upload.
      else if (data.errorCode == 3) {
        console.log(data);
      }
  }
});
```

When I upload image I get following error:

```
Object { errorCode=1, errorStatus="Bad link."}
```

And this is response that I get:

```
{"link":"7d59d61.jpg"}
```

What seem to be a problem?

[Froala image upload documentation](http://editor.froala.com/docs/image-upload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return the absolute image path :

```
$link = array("link" => '/img/media/'.$slika);
```

Because Froala looks for it to http://example.com/7d59d61.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the image cannot be loaded from the returned link. You'd have to make sure that the image can be accessed from it. Froala Editor uses the link you return for `src` attribute from `img` tag. I think you'd have to do something like:

```
$link = array("link" => $slika . 'public/img/media');
```